# g_bus_get_sync returns NULL, GError message also null

Tags: embedded-linux, glib

Trying to get a connection to dbus

```
g_bus_get_sync (G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION /* G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM */,
                NULL,
                &g_error)))
```

The function call returns NULL and g_error->message is also NULL, so I can't even see what the trouble is. Any ideas on where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g_error must be NULL:

```
GError * g_error = NULL
```

Otherwise an assertion is triggered. This assertion was invisible to me as I was running the code on an embedded system where stdout was not readily available.